# Need help with google sheets, sending info from one sheet to another, but allowing the second sheet to be modifiable!

Tags: google-sheets

Guys for example I have this master sheet, which has one specific column that I want to filter by. for example it has different job titles, and I want that to be on another sheet so I can create "shortlists" for new applicants.

However, I would need data on shortlists to be permanent and not movable, so that changes in the master sheet don't affect it!

Comment: Have you looked at [Create in-cell dropdown with filtered range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26287028/1330560) on StackOverflow? Looks like your problem.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].